# Illustrator brush and pentool line. Visually same thickness, why there is a difference in points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I created an illustration using pentool and brush in Illustrator. While I was trying to asses if the thickness of lines would be good enough for the printer I realized that my lines made with brush and pen tool, even if look they same, they have a different thickness in points. See the screenshot.

[image]

The line made by pentool has more than 1 pt so it is sufficient to print. The line made with brush looks even a bit thicker, even though Illustrator sais it has only 0.56 pt. Should I just assume that brush lines are ok for printing, becuase they are visually as thick as 1,3pt pen tool lines?

Can someone explain why there is this difference occuring?

Maybe brush settings has something to do with it? I attach the screen below.
[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use a brush, the stroke thickness is effectively a percentage relative to the brush's default size - so .56 means you get 56% of a 3-point brush - so around 1.68 pt.

Hope that helps.